# How does rails compiles the application.scss to public/aplication.css?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 4 with sass rails

```
gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.0"
```

I upgrade a hello rails application from 3.2 to rails 4.0.
I have an application.css.scss file and running 
    `rake assets:precompile`
I don't get any errors, there is a file public/application.css from a previous precompile command I guess and from my broswer I can see that is the one rails loads.
The problem is that is not been updated.
How can I compile the application.css.scss over a previous one.

Answer (score 0):

On rails 4 non fingerprinted versions of assets (ie application.css rather than `application-202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70`) are no longer created

Comment: So what do I have to do ?

Comment: why do you need the non fingerprinted version?

Comment: What's the non fingerprinted version ?
How can I switch to a fingerprinted version ?

Comment: Fingerprint means the compiled asset name contains a checksum. You'll use that automatically if you use stylesheet_link_tag